# Repo errors when doing apt-get update

Tags: 10.10, repository

This question is posted as a follow on the the missing GPG keys Q I posted here: 
[Many of my signatures/public keys for my repos dissappeared!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36092/many-of-my-signatures-public-keys-for-my-repos-dissappeared)

Here is the output when trying to apt-get update:

> Err http://ppa.launchpad.net
>    maverick/main Sources
>   404  Not Found Err http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick/main
>   i386 Packages
>   404  Not Found Get:10 http://dl.google.com stable Release
>   [1,347B]
>   Get:11 http://dl.google.com
>   stable/main i386 Packages [470B]
>   Get:12 http://dl.google.com
>   stable/main i386 Packages [737B]
>   Fetched 5,749B in 12s (445B/s)
>   W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com maverick
>   Release: The following signatures were
>   invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5
>   Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key
>    W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick
>   Release: The following signatures were
>   invalid: BADSIG 61E091672E206FF0
>   Launchpad nautilus-elementary W: GPG
>   error: http://ppa.launchpad.net
>   maverick Release: The following
>   signatures were invalid: BADSIG
>   9DAD42D740C11E40 Launchpad Cloudsn
>   Reporitory W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net maverick
>   Release: The following signatures were
>   invalid: BADSIG B725097B3ACC3965
>   Launchpad lffl W: Failed to fetch http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/intrepid-i386/arch/./Packages.gz
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimongard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz
>   404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimongard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to
>   download, they have been ignored, or
>   old ones used instead.

I'm not sure how or why these errors have come about or how to fix.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and tag it with whatever version of ubuntu you're running?

Comment: @Jorge: I think he's running Maverick, seeing `gb.archive.ubuntu.com maverick`.

Comment: Ah right, I thought this might have been a typical "ppa's not ready yet for 11.04". The VLC one is obviously out of date, can't explain the others though.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not really about GPG keys, but if you look at the output you will find a lot of "*404 Not Found*" errors. Looks like some repositories were removed or you're having trouble connecting to the LaunchPad servers.

BTW to fix that one key you can try this (it won't solve the 404s):

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3ACC3965 && gpg --export -a 3ACC3965 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting the vlc nightlies and webd8 repos and the others miraculously sorted themselves out :D